# Embed plugin for tinymce4

Tags: embed, flash, tinymce-4

Is there any embed plugin for tinymce4? I need to choose from a list of uploaded swf files, when Inserting an embed(swf flash) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TinyMce4 [Media Plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:media) has embed capabilities. It can easily be used to insert embed codes generated by common services like Youtube, Vimeo, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is kind of dead. Maybe this free filemanager and an MP4 file instead?
http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/demo.php